# How to verify that the text is written in two lines Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

In my test i must verify that the text of the Button is written in two lines:
Example:
Line 1
Line 2

```
<div class="ClassName">
Line 1
<br/>
<br/>
Line 2
</div>
```

The only Solution that I find is to verify that this balise contain the two texts et it work but that didn't verify that the text is written in two lines.

The xpath that I use is the folowing:

```
.//div[text()[contains(.,"Line 2")] and text()[contains(.,"Line 2")]]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your example, you could use the following xpath to only get the `div` if the `div` contains the text 'Line 1' and 'Line 2' and more than one `br` tag

`//div[contains(., 'Line 1') and contains(., 'Line 2') and count(br) > 1]`

Comment: Yes is not a bad idea! Thanks @marcel

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!